# unknown column 'cities.city' in 'field list'

Tags: sqoop

> unknown column 'cities.city' in 'field list'

```
sqoop import \
--connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/sivam_db \
--username root \
--password cloudera \
--query 'select cities.city as ccity,normcities.city as ncity from cities full join normcities using(id) where $CONDITIONS' \
--split-by id \
--target-dir /user/duplicatecolumn \
--m 1 \
--boundary-query "select min(id),max(id) from cities" \
--mapreduce-job-name fjoin \
--direct
```

I have checked all the posts related to this error and tried too, but still not resolved.

Schema of Cities:

create table cities(id int not null auto_increment,country varchar(30) not null,city varchar(30) not null, primary key (id));

Schema of normcities:

create table normcities(id int not null auto_increment,country_id int not null,city varchar(30) not null, primary key(id));

Comment: please share the schema for cities.

Comment: Put that in the question details and not the comments.

Answer (score 0):

In the above query in sqoop command, the output will be having 2 columns which display city names and this is only specified in the select statement and no other columns are retrieved. So full join gives an error as we filter only matched city names..

so remove the word 'full' and run the commnad.

we will get output.